# Join the 3 tables of database to get one table full and one column from table 2

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I need full table from `customer_account` and one column commission from company commission
in table `ewallet_fund_transfer` primary key is `id`, that is reference key in `company_commission`.  I want commission in front of this reference id.

```
function account_summary($userId, $acId)
{
    $this->db->select('customer_account.*,company_commission.commission');
    $this->db->from('customer_account');
    $this->db->join('company_commission', 'customer_account.customerID=company_comession.customer_id','inner');
    $this->db-> where('customerID', $userId);
    $this->db-> where('curr_ac_id', $acId);
    $this->db-> where('ewallet_fund_transfer.id=company_comession.reference_id');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: your last where references a table that doesnt exist in the query ... anyways when using join it always uses inner if no parameter is sent so you can omit the 'inner' in your join

Comment: You also mispelt `company_commission` as `company_comession`.